# Getting to put a dollar sign in the answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, currency

When I try to do this code down here, I get a differing answer than what is expected

```
print("Cost of purchasing",color,"paint:",'$',(cost))
```

I get this: `Cost of purchasing red paint: $ 35`

Instead of this: `Cost of purchasing red paint: $35`

How do I get rid of the space after putting in the dollar sign in quotes when doing this code in python 3? And btw this is part of a bigger question as I have issues with the way it would be. formatted.

Comment: I could not quite replicate it.  But it is possible that the parenthesis around `cost` makes it a collection.  Not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

Use plusses:

```
print("Cost of purchasing: " + color + "Paint: $" + cost)
```

Or even better - formatting:

```
print(f"Cost of purchasing: {color} Paint: ${cost}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Passing multiple values to a print statement puts the separator between them, which is by default a space. If you don't want the space, the easiest way to change that would be to concatenate the items with a `+` instead of printing both of them.

```
print("Cost of purchasing",color,"paint:",'$' + (cost))
```

Comment: Using the `+` operator on strings in Python is inefficient and should not be done. Use string formatting or (in newer Python versions) `f`-strings instead: `f"Cost of purchasing: {color} Paint: ${cost}"`

Comment: @KlausD. Just curious, how exactly so? In terms of time, from what I've seen from others and results on my machine, concatenation and f-strings tend to be pretty close and go back and forth even on large sample sizes, but `.format()` is quite a bit slower. Since the performance of concatenation is pretty good, I don't see a whole lot of reason to go against personal preference.

Comment: Using the `+` operator n times creates n+1 objects that increase in size and have to be garbage collected.